# How to get back to the previously opened activity without data lost

Tags: android, android-activity

I have open activities like this

Activity-A(Get the User Personal Details)  -->

Activity-B(Getting the User Contact Info) -->

Activity-C(Getting the User Credit Card Details) -->

Activity-D(Credit Card Verification)

Now from the Activity-D, I need to move to the Activity-B wihtout loosing user entered data on the Activity-B

I have tried `finish()` menthod on Activity-D But It fails.

I have open every activity using the following method. Example from Activtiy-A to Activty-B

```
 Intent intent_B = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class)
startActivity(intent_B);
```

How to I resume the Activity-B from Activity-D

Comment: use saveInstanceState to handle these events.. Read documentation here.. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: Just call the activity b from activity d again

Comment: @M.S.P how do i call activtiy B from activity D. It creates as new Activity without any data I have entered

Comment: Pass your data using the key value pair or Buffer. But even I would suggest you to go with saveinstancestate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solutions for your problem.

you Should call `finish()` before navigate to Activity D.

```
Intent intent_D = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityD.class)
startActivity(intent_D);
finish();
```

this will finish Activity C  and Activity A and B are still in background. so when you Click Backpress or call `finish()` on Activity  D, you will be navigate on Activity B and your data will be available without any extra effort.

Comment: Welcome!! @nifcody

Answer (score 1):

1. Store/Restore whole required data of activity B to [savedInstanceState](https://stackoverflow.com/q/151777/3379437).
2. Start activity B from activity D with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

This lead to behavior you exactly need:

- activity C & D is cleared from backstack
- previously created activity B is opened
- User can return from activity D to activity C by clicking back button
- Also we prevent data from loosing in case removing invisible activities from memory by system

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this would be to use Either `static` variables or `Singleton` class. Please find singleton explained here:
[link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternSingleton/article.html)

As for static variables, please look here:
[link](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-for-beginners-static-variables-what-are-they.html)

Answer (score -1):

Here's

**IN Activity 1 ::**

```
int REQ_INT=888;
Intent intent_B = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class)
startActivityForResult(intent_B,REQ_INT);
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQ_INT: 
                 //DO your stuff here after getting in this activity again..
                 break;
            }
    }
```

**In Activity 2::**

After finishing the task for that activity .

Just

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

you can pass the data to that activity with intent..

Or go see these link [Link1](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example) [Link 2](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: and where is here an answer on particular question?